# Is there a CALDAV plugin for Eclipse Mylyn?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, caldav, zimbra

We use Zimbra at work and I'm thinking I should centralize my todo list into one thing. I'm starting to lean towards that one thing being Eclipse, given how awesome Mylyn is. Is there a remote repository plugin to Mylyn so that it can connect to CALDAV calendars / task lists?